# Convert printed letters to keyboard typing animation in python 3

Tags: python

How to convert words to keyboard typing animation in Python version 3?
It means that the words that I specify will be printed letter by letter
By which library should I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there any example that you can share that might help us understand the question? Please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any specific libraries, just `sleep()` a bit between each letter.

```
import time

mytext = "hello world"

for letter in mytext:
    print(letter, end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

So whats up with the extra parameters to print?

`end=""` is used to say to print to not append an new line after your text, you can replace this with any character, for example `end=" "` will add a space between each letter.

`flush=True` tells python to not buffer the output and print it directly to the output, else you might just get a long delay and then all letters come at once.

The `time.sleep(1)` part is how many seconds should be between letters, if you want it a bit more organic you can add some randomness

```
import time
import random

min_time = 0.2 # atleast 0.2 seconds between letters

mytext = "hello world"

for letter in mytext:
    print(letter, end="", flush=True)
    delay_time = min_time + random.random() # will be between 0.2 and 1.2 seconds.
    time.sleep(delay_time)
```

Comment: Then its polite to mark is as the right answer so people see its answered :)